# Tikz Mindmap Level 2 Alignment

Tags: tikz-trees, mindmaps

How can I align Level 2 node (lines) in my mind map.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\tikzset{
set angles for level/.style={level #1/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
level/.append style={set angles for level=#1}% solution 1
}
\tikzset{
non-concept/.style={
    rectangle,
    text width=15em,
    text=black,
    align=left,
    font=\large,
},
cncc east/.style={
    edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode.east) to[out=0, in=180] (\tikzchildnode.south west)
        -- (\tikzchildnode.south east)
    }
}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1 concept/.append style={font=\large}, level 1 concept/.append style={
    level distance=150}]
\path[mindmap, concept color=Aquamarine]
node[concept] {ICF Core \\ Competencies}[clockwise from=45]
child[concept color=blue!20!white, text width=8em] {
    node[concept] (def) {Setting the Foundation}
    [grow=right, sibling distance=10ex, ]
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Meeting Ethical Guidelines \& Professional Standards} edge from parent[cncc east] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing the Coaching Agreement} edge from parent[cncc east] }
}
child[concept color=Pink, text width=8em]  { node[concept] {Co-creating the \\ Relationship} 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc east] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] } 
   }
     child[concept color=Bisque, text width=8em]{ node[concept] {Communicating Effectively} 
     child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc east] }
     child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] }    
     child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] }    
 }
 child[concept color=Cyan, text width=8em]  { node[concept] {Facilitating Learning \& Results} 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc east] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc east] }     
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to align with what exactly?

Comment: I just want it to look good. Look at cyan bubble (Facilitating Learn..). The line should go out from the other side so they don't go over the bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have more patience than me, I suggest abandoning the twiddly bits and going for something a bit simpler.

Here's a possible start:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\tikzset{
  set angles for level/.style={level #1/.append style={sibling angle=360/(\the\tikznumberofchildren+4)}},
  level/.append code={
    \edef\tempa{#1}\edef\tempb{1}
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\tikzset{level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}}\else\tikzset{set angles for level=#1}\fi},
%     set angles for level=#1},% solution 1
  non-concept/.style={
    rectangle,
    text width=15em,
    text=black,
    align=left,
    font=\large,
  },
  cncc/.style={ edge from parent path={ (\tikzparentnode.#1) to [bend right] (\tikzchildnode)   } },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1 concept/.append style={font=\large, level distance=150}]
  \path[mindmap, concept color=Aquamarine, grow cyclic]
  node[concept] {ICF Core \\ Competencies}%[clockwise from=45]
  child[concept color=blue!20!white] {
    node[concept] (def) {Setting the Foundation}
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Meeting Ethical Guidelines \& Professional Standards} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing the Coaching Agreement} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
  }
  child[concept color=Pink]  { node[concept] {Co-creating the \\ Relationship} 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=south] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=south] } 
  }
  child[concept color=Bisque]{ node[concept] {Communicating Effectively} 
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=east] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=east] }    
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=south] }    
  }
  child[concept color=Cyan]  { node[concept] {Facilitating Learning \& Results} 
    [clockwise from=90]
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=west] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=north] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=east] }     
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: simpler (but legible)]

Comment: I love this solution to use level 2 as annotations. I posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643599/mindmap-conditional-anchoring-for-level-2) following your great answer, but no luck so far. If I may ask you to just take a look if you have a chance. Merci ! :)