# Mindmap - conditional anchoring for level 2

Tags: tikz-pgf

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499310/tikz-mindmap-level-2-alignment) pretty solution by cfr enables to use **the nodes at level 2 to style them like annotation**.

Very different approach from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527832/adding-info-boxes-to-a-mindmap) or [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508907/how-to-add-information-to-a-mindmap) where extra nodes are added **outside** the mindmap itslef.

However I am struggling with the anchor of `level 2` so that it would look more harmonious like the following (I cheated on paint to show the expected result).

I imagine the idea is to have a moving anchor (`east` for `level 2` nodes on the left side of , `west` anchor on the right side nodes of the mindmap ? more granularity, sloped to follow the path from level 1 ? I do not know what could be feasible).
That said, I'm unable to have a starting point on how to differenciate the cases :/

[image]

```
% original MWE from cfr.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\tikzset{
  set angles for level/.style={level #1/.append style={sibling angle=360/(\the\tikznumberofchildren+4)}},
  level/.append code={
    \edef\tempa{#1}\edef\tempb{1}
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\tikzset{level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}}\else\tikzset{set angles for level=#1}\fi},
%     set angles for level=#1},% solution 1
  non-concept/.style={
    rectangle,
    text width=15em,
    text=black,
    align=left,
    font=\large,
  },
  cncc/.style={ edge from parent path={ (\tikzparentnode.#1) to [bend right] (\tikzchildnode)   } },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1 concept/.append style={font=\large, level distance=150}]
  \path[mindmap, concept color=Aquamarine, grow cyclic]
  node[concept] {ICF Core \\ Competencies}%[clockwise from=45]
  child[concept color=blue!20!white] {
    node[concept] (def) {Setting the Foundation}
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Meeting Ethical Guidelines \& Professional Standards} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing the Coaching Agreement} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
  }
  child[concept color=Pink]  { node[concept] {Co-creating the \\ Relationship} 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=south] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=south] } 
  }
  child[concept color=Bisque]{ node[concept] {Communicating Effectively} 
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=east] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=east] }    
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=south] }    
  }
  child[concept color=Cyan]  { node[concept] {Facilitating Learning \& Results} 
    [clockwise from=90]
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc=west] }
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=west] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=north] } 
    child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc=east] }     
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna perfect align the path with the level 2 entries. You need manually adjust them. Because it depends on the text width, minimum size and anchors of the entries. I add two arguments in the `non-concept/.style` and one more argument in the `cncc/.style`. In `non-concept/.style`, the first argument #1 is to specify the text width and the second argument #2 is to specify minimum size of the level 2 node. In `cncc/.style`, the first argument #1 is still the anchor of the level 1 parent node, the second argument #2 is the anchor of the level 2 child node. I also add frames to each level 2 entry, in order to see effect explicitly (comment the `draw` in `non-concept/.style` will make no frames). You can adjust those arguments to make the figure close to the expected result in your question. Also in some case, you might need to use `shift` to manually adjust the locations of the level 2 entry (e.g. `child[shift={(2.5cm,-3cm)},level distance=5cm]`).

Here is the code:

```
% original MWE from cfr.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\tikzset{
set angles for level/.style={level #1/.append style={sibling angle=360/(\the\tikznumberofchildren+4)}},
level/.append code={
\edef\tempa{#1}\edef\tempb{1}%
\ifx\tempa\tempb\tikzset{level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}}\else\tikzset{set angles for level=#1}\fi},
%     set angles for level=#1},% solution 1
non-concept/.style 2 args={
draw, % comment to make no frames
minimum size=#2,
text width=#1,
text=black,
align=left,
font=\large,
},
cncc/.style n args={2}{ edge from parent path={ (\tikzparentnode.#1) to [bend right] (\tikzchildnode.#2)   } },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1 concept/.append style={font=\large, level distance=150}]
\path[mindmap, concept color=Aquamarine, grow cyclic] 
node[concept] {ICF Core \\ Competencies}%[clockwise from=45]
child[concept color=blue!20!white] {
node[concept] (def) {Setting the Foundation}
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={14em}{1cm}] {Meeting Ethical Guidelines \& Professional Standards} edge from parent[cncc={west}{north}] }
child[shift={(-2cm,1.5cm)},level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={12em}{1cm}] {Establishing the Coaching Agreement} edge from parent[cncc={west}{north west}]}
}
child[concept color=Pink] { 
node[concept] {Co-creating the \\ Relationship} 
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={14em}{1cm}] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc={south}{north west}] }
child[level distance=6cm] { node[non-concept={9em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={south}{south west}] } 
}
child[text width=7em,concept color=Bisque]{ node[concept] {Communicating Effectively} [clockwise from=0]
child[shift={(2.5cm,-3cm)},level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={14em}{1cm}] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc={east}{south west}] }
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={9em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={east}{west}] }    
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={9em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={south}{north west}] }    
}
child[concept color=Cyan]  { node[concept] {Facilitating Learning \& Results} 
[clockwise from=90]
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={14em}{1cm}] {Establishing Trust \& Intimacy with the Client} edge from parent[cncc={west}{north}] }
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={8.8em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={west}{north east}] } 
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={8.8em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={north}{east}] } 
child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept={8.8em}{0.5cm}] {Coaching Presence} edge from parent[cncc={east}{south east}] }     
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]